# Tensorflow Object detection API error on windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I have gone through the installation and installed all the dependencies and have done all the steps. But when I try to run the object_detection_tutorial, I get the following error:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a66a6238863e> in <module>()
      3 from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
      4 import utils
----> 5 from utils import label_map_util

F:\models-master\models-master\research\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py in <module>()
     20 import tensorflow as tf
     21 from google.protobuf import text_format
---> 22 from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
     23 
     24 

F:\models-master\models-master\research\object_detection\protos\string_int_label_map_pb2.py in <module>()
     39       message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
     40       is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
---> 41       options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
     42     _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
     43       name='id', full_name='object_detection.protos.StringIntLabelMapItem.id', index=1,

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'
```

I get the mentioned error after running this line:

```
from utils import label_map_util
```

Comment: did you try setting the environment path for models?

Comment: I did, I fixed it by reinstalling tensorflow and using a new environment.